# VBA code for Vlookup exact match (false) should work?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, exact-match

My code works when I use True on the last argument. The problem is that it must be an exact match, otherwise the code brings me the incorrect values. However, when I change the last argument to False I get the error 1004

> Unable to get vlookup property of the WorksheetFunction class

Here is my code:

```
Range("AW" & i) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet2.Range("B" & i), Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Range("A1"), Sheet3.Range("B" & lastrow)), 2, False)
```

I just want to make this vlookup give me the correct values. Therefore, I need to make the exact match argument work.

Comment: It is not the case of the vlookup create any type of error, I did the vlookup in the worksheet and they all have the correct numbers. So some of the error handlers are useless in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this ...

```
Range("AW" & i) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet2.Range("B" & i), Sheet3.Range("A1:B" & lastrow), 2, False)
```

... you need to wrap the single range in the second parameter.  It's not 100% tested but I mocked something up locally working on a single sheet that worked.

You could also do something like this using **INDEX** and **MATCH** ...

```
Range("AW" & i) = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheet3.Range("A1:B" & lastrow), WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet2.Range("B" & i), Sheet3.Range("A1:B" & lastrow)))
```

If you have the potential for items not finding a match, you'll need to perform the appropriate error checking.